# Table.compute() C# MIN, MAX and AVG

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

I have a problem with code below:

```
val_par_Decimal_Min = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("MIN(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + " <> 0")?.ToString() ?? "0"), 2).ToString().Replace(",", ".");

val_par_Decimal_Max = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("MAX(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + " <> 0")?.ToString() ?? "0"), 2).ToString().Replace(",", ".");

val_par_Decimal_Med = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("AVG(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + " <> 0")?.ToString() ?? "0"), 2).ToString().Replace(",", ".");
```

I am collecting some data and saving in a table.

The column is created automatically and the type is decimal.

I want to calculate the minimum, maximum and average of the column disregarding the value 0.

However the following error is occurring:

> "The input string was not in a correct format"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to split your expressions to smaller, preferably atomic statements. So instead of `Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(...))` use temporary variables for the statements in brakets to evaluate where exactly you get the error. Alternativly you may also use the wquickwatch for the inner expression and see what they evaluate to. I suppose the error occurs when calling `ToDecimal`, because the value provided can´t be converted. But without the value that *is* provided it´s impossible to say exactly.

Comment: thanks for your help. Below is the solution to my problem:

Answer (score 0):

After Him's help, below is the solution to my problem:

```
val_par_Decimal_Min = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("MIN(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + "<>" + 0).ToString()) ? "0" : dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("MIN(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + "<>" + 0).ToString()), 2).ToString().Replace(",", ".");

val_par_Decimal_Max = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("MAX(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + "<>" + 0).ToString()) ? "0" : dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("MAX(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + "<>" + 0).ToString()), 2).ToString().Replace(",", ".");

val_par_Decimal_Med = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("AVG(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + "<>" + 0).ToString()) ? "0" : dsTabDados.Tables[EquipTrigger[TGR]].Compute("AVG(" + col.ColumnName + ")", col.ColumnName + "<>" + 0).ToString()), 2).ToString().Replace(",", ".");
```

The value that was returning in my calculation was null, trying to convert to integer was giving the error I quoted.

To solve it I have added a condition in which it is ***"string.IsNullorEmpty"*** if true changes to "0" if it is false it informs the value that it returned.
After this step I use toDecimal.

Solved problem.